# Old prelim exam problem for $f(z)$ is analytical function on an open neighborhood $G$ of the unit circle, with $|f(z)|=1$ when $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytical function on an open neighborhood $G$ of the unit circle $\partial D$, with $|f(z)|=1$ when $z \in \partial D$. Show that

$f(z)=1/\overline{f(1/\bar{z})}$

for all $z$ in the neighborhood of the unit circle $\partial D$.

I don't know how to start, or what theorem I should use. I have an exam after two days
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the Schwarz reflection principle?

Comment: Yes. Actually I don't understand the question very well (can you explain it if you do, plz?). Where is the symmetry in the domain that I can apply Schwarz reflection principle on? And if there is, then how to do that?

Comment: If you know the reflection principle, consider as another hint the function $\phi(w) = \frac{iw+1}{iw-1}$

Comment: I am not sure how I can use this function.

Comment: You said you know the reflection principle.  The reflection principle is for functions where?  This is a Mobius transformation.  Mobius transformations do what?  Play with this.  If you're going to take a qualifying exam these things should be very familiar to you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but, how can $\overline{f(1/\bar z)}$ be an analytic function? The circle reflection map is orientation preserving and so is $f$. It seems to me that by taking its complex conjugate we are producing an orientation changing function.

Comment: No I only have a first midterm, and the professor posted these problems as suggested ones for the test, so this is the first time to hear about these things. I had the reflection principle as a theorem without any application.

Comment: Perhaps you may reflect the function $f|_U$ (restricted to the inner part of the circle) through the arc, get a new function $f^*$, which coincides with $f$ on an open set, thus $f^*=f$, so $f$ satisfy the required equation by the construction.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the essence of the comments by Euler....IS_ALIVE.

Try writing $f(z)$ as a Laurent series about the origin.  This will give you the Laurent expansion for $\overline{f(\frac{1}{\bar{z}})}$ and yields some relationship between the Laurent coefficients of each function.

Now show this relationship holds by computing the Laurent coefficients of $\overline{f(\frac{1}{\bar{z}})}$ via integrals.  Don't forget to use that the fact that on the boundary $\bar{f}f=1$ and $\frac{1}{\bar{z}}=z$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that these functions are both holomorphic and equal for all $z$ such that $|z|=1$. (The map $z\mapsto 1/\overline{z}$ fixes the unit circle pointwise.)  This means that the difference vanishes on a non-discrete subset.